# Get match length in parsec

Tags: haskell, parsec

Parsec's `parse pattern "(some_input)" input` returns the parsed data (as I specified in `pattern`.

How to know how much of `input` have it consumed (the pattern is not anchored with eof)? I don't want to add length tracking though the all `pattern`'s internals (if discards some parts of input).

Comment: You would have to use `getInput` before the parse to get the input stream and use `length` to get the length of the input stream. After the parse compare the starting length to the length of input remaining.

Comment: length (getInput (hGetContents socket)) => Infinity?

Comment: I want to parse the header and determine where the body does appear.

Comment: @stephen tetley, getInput is useful in my case, but it does not solve the task. Consider the infinite input. Input length both before and after parse is infinity.

Comment: Hi Vi - getting the consumed length is a peculiar use-case which Parsec doesn't naturally handle. You might want to look an see if other parser combinator libraries support it, or in the extreme case you might have to write your own parser combinator library.

Comment: OK, considering this as an answer: "1. It is not possible in Parsec, 2. If header and body then use getInput, 3. Can be done in other parsers".

Answer (score 1):

1. It is not easy with Parsec;
2. If it is needed to skip header you can grab the rest of input using `getInput`;
3. May be other parser libraries can do this.

(the answer is based on comments to the question)